# DSE VM from Datastax Cassandra-Spark tutorial throws Errors on starting in VirtualBox

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

Running into an error with a (possibly?) corrupted VM from a Datastax tutorial on Cassandra with Spark:
https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-apache-spark-and-cassandra

After a couple download attempts to my Mac running El Capitan; I was able to successfully download what seems to be a complete vm.  I'm using VirtualBox v5.0.*

Size of Spark.vbox:  9174

Once I dbl-clk on *.vbox from Finder window, I get the following error:

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine DS320 Spark.
>
> Could not open the medium '~/SPARK-DS/DS320 Spark/box-disk1.vmdk'.
>
> VD: error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file '~/SPARK-DS/DS320
>   Spark/box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).
>
> Result Code:  NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Component:    MediumWrap
>   Interface:    IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda}

================================================================

Here's what I've tried:

1) Starting another pre-existing Cassandra VM -- this worked great.  So, there's nothing wrong with my Virtual Box.

2) Removing this tutorial's DSE VM -- this gives an error:
Could not delete the medium storage unit '~/SPARK-DS/DS320 Spark/box-disk1.vmdk'.

VD: error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file '~/SPARK-DS/DS320 Spark/box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).

3) Looked at File/Virtual Media Manager

Cannot see that box-disk1

(at one point, I could see it and and hit selection to Release it)

4) Physically deleted the VM file under ~/VirtualBox VMs/Machines

then re-added it by just dbl-clk of the downloaded *.vbox

SADLY ... NO DICE; SAME ERROR!

Comment: Got this working; but VM files in *.vbox cannot be Imported as an Appliance; just Added from the original download directory location.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working; but VM files in *.vbox cannot be Imported as an Appliance.  Instead, I just Added from the original 'Downloads' directory location by dbl-clk on *.vbox file.  I had originally copied the downloaded 'DSE 320' folder to a different location.  However, this didn't change the files' internal  references to the *.vmdk disk locations; and so VirtualBox couldn't find the file dependencies and had failed to startup the VM.  This implies that I need to permanently retain that 'DSE320' folder in my Downloads directory!  I suspect the easiest solution maybe for Datastax to consistently provide files in the standard-importable *.ovf format!